# Executing Python script on a CIFS share

Tags: linux, python

I have a windows share that has been mounted on a linux machine using a CIFS Share

I want to execute a python script on the windows share as a particular user in linux

If I do

```
sudo su [username]
path/to/python /mnt/sharedfolder/pythonscript.py
```

everything works fine

but if I do

```
sudo -u [username] path/to/python /mnt/sharedfolder/pythonscript.py
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/mnt/scripts/automation/ubuntuPullGeodatabases.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I get the error above. Its like the script is executing on the windows machine rather than the linux machine since there is a `C:\Python27\` folder with the python executable on the windows machine.

Now if I do

```
sudo -u [username] /path/to/python --version
Python 2.7.14
```

It works fine

I should also mention that I am specifying `path/to/python` because its not the standard installation of python its a custom python from a different software.

Any ideas?